# Excel index match: If date week number matches date?

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I have 2 excel spreadsheets, sheet 1 and sheet 2:

Sheet 2

```
Col F (Date)   Col G (Item No)  Col H (Supplier code)   Col I (PO Number)
21/12/2016         12345                 123            PO1111
18/12/2016         5555                  2468           PO2222
                                         123            po982
```

Sheet 1

```
Column F (Week No or date)    Column G (Item No)    Col H (Supplier   Col I (Formula) Code)   
51                            12345                 123
18/12/2016                    5555                  2468
```

In Column I on sheet 1, i want to add my index match formula:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!D1, MATCH(F4&G4&H4,Sheet2!A:A&Sheet2!B:B&Sheet2!C:C, 0))
```

This should return the PO number from column I on sheet 2 where column F, G and H match.

This works fine. And from the example above, this formula would return a result for the last row:

```
18/12/2016                    5555               2468         PO2222
```

You might have noticed that the first row in column (F) on sheet 1 has a week number 50 - yet there is a date of 21/12/2016 in column F on sheet 2.

By rights this would not give a matching result.

However, Column F on sheet 2 will either have a week number or a specific date in it. And if this is the case, i want my formula to check for both a matching date or where a matching date is not found, check if the date falls within that week number? So for instance 21/12/2016 would fall into week 51 (week beginning monday).

Is there a way i can amend my index match formula accordingly to get this result?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you use a helper column. For eg. in sheet 2 COl J `= WEEKNUM(F2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a helper column in `Sheet 2 col J` to get the week number for the dates in Col F. In sheet1 I used this formula for col I

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!I:I,SUMPRODUCT(IF(YEAR(F3)<2016,(Sheet2!J:J=F3),(Sheet2!F:F=F3))*(Sheet2!G:G=G3)*(Sheet2!H:H=H3)*ROW(Sheet2!I:I)))
```

The below part of the formula

```
IF(YEAR(F3)<2016,(Sheet2!J:J=F3),(Sheet2!F:F=F3))
```

checks if the year for date is less than 2016. If week number was entered, `Year()` will return a value of 1900. if true it compares the week number to the col K in sheet 2 else it compares the dates in col F for both sheets.

[image]

Comment: Thanks this is brilliant

Comment: is the below part of the formula you stated the formula that needs to go in column J that gets the week number ?

Comment: NO. `J2 = WEEKNUM(F2)` and fill down

Comment: OK and which column does this go in? IF(YEAR(F3)<2016,(Sheet2!J:J=F3),(Sheet2!F:F=F3))

Comment: That's already in the first formula i posted. I was just explaining a part of the formula(First one)

Comment: see updated question (sheet 2) your index match formula is returning the PO number PO982 where the supplier number and item number and date do not match and also where the date is empty.

Comment: Can you try and enter the formula as an array formula i.e. enter the formula (or press F2 if the formula is already there) and press Ctrl+Shift+Enter

Comment: Sorry the formula is already entered as an array. Forgot to mention

Comment: i added the additional row(PO982) in sheet 2. No output in Sheet 1 changed. I am not sure what values in sheet 1 give you the output of PO982